# I am adding js form my block but it's not working

Tags: block, magento-1.9

Here is my code , anyone can you please solve my problem

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Block_Custom extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('jquery/myjs.js');
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the head block is already rendered then it has no effect. You have to make sure the js is added to the head after loadLayout() has been called in the controller action and before you call renderLayout() in the same action.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/add-javascript-file-to-head-for-create-block#answer-4992